# Declare and initialize vector<vector<int>> separately

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I am trying to declare `vector<vector<int>>` in header and then initialize/use in cpp. How could I initialize such a vector in source?

What I am trying to do is below.

header.h

```
vector<vector<int>> allints;
```

source.cpp

```
allints = new vector(2, vector<int>);
```

Comment: Follow the advice in Igor Tandetnik's answer, but for future reference to use `new` successfully you need to assign the result to a pointer. eg: `vector<vector<int>> *allints;` Do not do this here because the given answer solves the problem you were struggling with and 2 others you hadn't found yet.

Comment: Although there is rarely a reason to create dynamic vectors so vector pointers should normally be avoided.

Comment: You can't do it that way in C++.   An object of type `vector<vector<int>>` is not initialised by operator `new` in that way.   This is C++, not Java.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In header:

```
extern vector<vector<int>> allints;
```

In source file:

```
vector<vector<int>> allints(2);
```

Comment: it seems I also need to declare it outside of the class. thank you.

Comment: What class? Your question doesn't mention any class.

Comment: I was trying to use that vector variable within the class. If I declare it outside of class and initialize in it, your answer is applicable.